# Firefox using serif font for "Helvetica" family after upgrade to 18.04

Tags: firefox, fonts, 18.04

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 (from 17.10), Firefox seems to have started using a serif font when the CSS says `font-family: Helvetica;`.  Naturally, this looks kind of jarring.  My first thought was that maybe some font got uninstalled during the upgrade, but I couldn't find any in the logs at a glance.  Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how it happened either, but I'm willing to bet the default font configuration was changed at some point during the way. I checked the `Language & Appearance` settings and noticed `Default (DejaVu Serif)` was selected, so I changed it to `Arial` (with the same font size) and it all went back to how it looked before the upgrade.

Comment: Interesting how that seems to have changed.  Changing to a sans serif font as the default seems to have addressed this, at least.